# Trying to return the linked list from the function but couldnot figure out why it is not working,

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

In the code below resultTree is passed from other function, I am trying to update the result tree but instead of value asssigned at the last I am getting value assigned at first(if I assign it) else I will get the empty value. Below is the code,

`

```
heaviest = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        mw = y.heaviestTree(graph, heaviest);
        System.out.println("heaviestTree: " + mw + " : " + heaviest);

 float heaviestTree(DiGraph G, LinkedList<Vertex> resultTree) {
        Set<Vertex> roots = rootVertices(G);


        LinkedList<Vertex>[] myList = new LinkedList[roots.size()];
        Float weight = (float) 0;
        Float[] weights = new Float[roots.size()];
        int i = 0;

        for (Vertex v : G.vertices())
            v.setColor(DiGraph.WHITE);

        for (Vertex v : roots) {

            weights[i]=(float) 0;
            LinkedList<Vertex> Temp= new LinkedList<Vertex>();
            Temp.add(v);


            resultTree.add(v); //For checking

            innerloop:
            for (Vertex neighbors : v.neighbors()) {
                if (neighbors.getColor() != DiGraph.BLACK) {
                    Temp.add(neighbors);
                    neighbors.setColor(DiGraph.BLACK);

                    weights[i]=weights[i]+ v.getEdge(neighbors).getWeight();

                }
                else{
                    myList[i]=null;
                    weights[i]=(float) 0;
                    break innerloop;
                }

            }
            myList[i]= Temp;

        i++;

        }

        System.out.println("# #"+resultTree);

        for (int c = 0; c < weights.length; c++)
        {

             if (weights[c] >weight)
             {
             weight = weights[c];
             resultTree = myList[c];

             }

        }


        if(resultTree.size()==0){

            return Float.NaN;
        }


        System.out.println("#  "+ resultTree);

        return weight;`
```

OutPut is

```
# #[[1], [3]]
#  [[1], [4], [0]]
heaviestTree: 12.9 : [[1], [3]]
```

But I was expecting

```
# #[[1], [3]]
#  [[1], [4], [0]]
heaviestTree: 12.9 : [[1], [4], [0]]
```

I have been struggling for hours to figure out what am I doing wrong, Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is **pass-by-value**. Therefore, this line here

```
resultTree = myList[c];
```

will not do what you believe it will do. Let's take it a step back. When you call `heaviestTree`, you pass in `heaviest`. What happens right after is a copy of a reference to the `LinkedList<Vertex>` is made. If you make changes to the linked list through the reference copy within the method, it will be applied to the actual linked list pointed to by `heaviest`. However, in the case of reassigning, it won't work. Let's say the reference copy was called `resultTree`. The line above will change what `resultTree` points to, not what `heaviest` points to. And since local variables/copies are discarded at the end of the method, you won't be able to make use of `resultTree` in your last print statement after `heaviestTree` is finished. This is also the reason as to why you see the correct tree being printed out when you print it inside the method. Because that linked list is the one pointed to by the reference copy `resultTree`, while `heaviest` is still pointing to the original linked list.

My suggestions for solving the problem,

1. Make a global `LinkedList<Vertex>` variable to hold the heaviest tree

or

2. Make the method return a `LinkedList<Vertex>` that represents the heaviest tree